# ValueChangeListener is not working on SelectOneRadio JSF

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener, selectoneradio

I have a selectOneRadio and i have binded this with ValueChangeListener. But the Listener is not getting called on SelectOneRadio. I am able to call this on SelectOneMenu. Please help me on this

```
<h:panelGrid id="TPLADMPGD867" columns="2" width="105%"
                                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:selectOneRadio id="polCasetype" value="#{TPLPolicyDataBean.coveredIndividualVO.polCasetype}" valueChangeListener="#{TPLPolicyControllerBean.valueChangeOnPolCaseType}">
                        <f:selectItems id="polCasetypelist"
                                        value="#{TPLPolicyDataBean.polCasetypelist}"/> 

    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And My Value Change Listener is as follows

```
public void valueChangeOnPolCaseType(ValueChangeEvent event){
  --
}
```

Scope for ControllerBean is correct.